# Showing the result of a WebClient-postback in an Browser Window from Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, webclient

I want to show the result of a WebClient-Postback in an new Browser-Popup-Window. As the "Navigate" and "Popup" methods of HtmlPage only support Get-requests, I issued an POST-request to an REST-Service via WebClient. But now I want to show the result (e.g. application/ms-excel or application/pdf) in an new Browser-Window.

Therefore, can I open an new BrowserWindow and set its contents as well as some corresponding http-headers with on-board means of Silverlight 4? Or even better, is an easier way to trigger the browser to do the POST-request to the service?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried going this route but the WebBrowser control is not opened to the developer. What I did as a temporary workaround was to open my webpage http://www.xyz.com/default.aspx inside the WebControl and let the page drive the rest.

Mike Taulty had an example for somthing like this, how you can use javascript to communicate back to the silverlight app through InvokeScript: 
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-html-hosting-in-the-webbrowser-control.aspx

I hope it helps!